# IncompatibleClassChangeError thrown at runtime with Micrometer

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, quarkus, micrometer

I'm facing the following issue

```
[ERROR] com.xyz.MyClass.myTest  Time elapsed: 2.073 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Method 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Builder 
io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer.builder(java.lang.String)' must be InterfaceMethodref constant
```

This comes from a prject being compiled and run with Java 11. It does however depend on libraries that have been compiled with Java 8, and some of them were coded with Scala.

I discarded root cause being conflict between different Micrometer versions as there is only one Micrometer version in the classpath:

```
[INFO] +- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.7.3:compile
```

The code compiles fine. This issue occurs at runtime. The above error is from a Quarkus test.

Any idea?

Comment: My guess is that you are mixing micrometer versions

Comment: how so? Only one is found the the classpath

Comment: Can you add the entire stacktrace and the `pom.xml`?

Comment: Can you also be clear about which version of Quarkus this is using?